# how to serve javascript wtih asp.net page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I don't know if the title is clear enough or not, but let me explain what I'm trying to do.

I have two webapps with written in asp.net with C#.

App A has the following html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="blah" src="http://somServer/AppB/page.aspx?p=q"></script>
```

App B receives above request and needs to inject javascript dynamically to the script tag above. I have the following code in App B's page.aspx but it doesn't work. I need App B to return pure javascript, not html.

```
namespace AppB
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       if(!Page.IsPostBack)
       {
         Response.Clear();
         Response.ClearContent();
         REsponse.ClearHeader();
         Response.AddHeader("content-type", "text/javascript");
         var p = Request.Query["p"];
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p))
         {
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "test", "alert('test');", false");
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: Why are you calling another .aspx page?  Is that a specific requirement?

Comment: When you say doesn't work...Does the resource load but with the incorrect content type? Can you maybe attach a screengrab of the request/response headers from FireBug.

Comment: @Infotekka, there is no error but the result is not what I expected.

Comment: @ TheGeek YouNeed, since AppB will be used/shared by many other web applications, that's why I'm building it as a stand alone web app.

Comment: @madcapnmckay request: GET http://someServer/AppB/Page.aspx?p=q HTTP/1.0 Accept: */* Referer: http://someServer/AppA/ Accept-Language: en-US User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0E) Connection: Keep-Alive Host: someServer Authorization: Negotiate {..a bunch of stuff..} Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Connection: keep-alive Date: Thu, 28 Jul 2011 19:59:29 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub X-Powered-By: ASP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use a `HttpHandler` rather than `Page` (see   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001) to serve non-HTML content.  This would allow you to write something like:

```
public class JavascriptHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
        string p = context.Request.QueryString["p"];
        string script = String.Format("alert('test - p={0}');", p);
        context.Response.Write(script);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way implement this with a web application project instead of a class library project? My guess is probably NO since Page class is probably way down the pipe already.

Comment: @myself, the answer is YES. I can add a Generic Handler (ashx) page.